# Audio resumes whenever bluetooth connects or disconnects - how do I stop this?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

This seems to be independent of which bluetooth device I connect/disconnect to (car audio, ear buds, etc), and is also independent of whatever the last app I was listening to (VLC, Pandora, etc).

When I tell an app to stop playing, I'd like it to STAY stopped... not automatically pick up where it left off simply because I stopped or started my car, or got in/out of range of one of my bluetooth audio devices.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the issue strictly related to Android Auto, or also on general Android devices (e.g. phones, tablets)?

Comment: This is independent of Android Auto.  I don't even have that installed on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Bluetooth Connect & Play app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player). It basically meant to start a specific music app playing when a specific Bluetooth device connects. But you can also select "Stop music from playing" option to keep any app from starting when the car connects to a Bluetooth device. I faced the similar issue on my Toyota and it did help.

Comment: Well, the app seemed to do the trick - thanks. It's unfortunate (and confusing) why I'd have to have an app to turn this behavior off, but hey... problem solved.

Comment: Good to hear that @Gazpacho. If it solved your problem, then you may accept my answer by clicking on the "Check" mark right next to my answer. When it turns green it means you've accepted the answer. Just a suggestion. It is up to you.

Comment: Using the app to restart VLC on Android 10 tablet. Works nicely with Bluetooth headphones. Haven't yet tested, but real reason I want it is for use in car. Currently pauses VLC when car ignition turned off: expecting VLC to restart when I start the car again. App very usefully sets option by target device, so I can leave smart TV unaffected.

Comment: Mate, this app wants access to make phone calls.  What the heck?